# Solving for $x$ in a Laplace equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

So I have this Laplace equation:

$$s^{2}x+4sx+5=\frac{s}{s-1}$$

And I want to solve for $x$. My result is the following:

$$x = \frac{5-4s}{s^{3}+3s^{2}-4s}$$

Which is also the same answer that for example WolframAlpha gives me. Turns out that this is kind of complicated to do partial fraction decomposition on to thereafter do inverse-Laplace on.

Now in the step-by-step solution for the whole problem (in my book) a nice solve for $x$ is stated, as the following:

$$x = \frac{s}{(s-1)(s^{2}+4s+5)}$$

So my question is: how do I go from the original Laplace equation to my books solution on how to solve $x$?

Comment: Turns out that there was mistake in the solution in the book. I have corrected it now in my question, however my question still remains - how do you solve it that nicely?

Comment: What more doe you want to solve for $x$? You got the letter by itself. Of course you can do partial fraction decomposition. (A very common tool for Laplace) The denom $(s+1)$ receives an $A$ in the num and the denom $(s^2+4s+5$ receives a $BX+C$ in its num. Do you know how to work that out?

Comment: Thereafter I want to do the inverse-Laplace of the right hand side, which is kind of complicated with how I solved x, but easy with how my book has solved x. So I'm wondering how to go from the original Laplace equation to the way my book has solved for x. How to go from $s^{2}x+4sx+5=\frac{s}{s-1}$ to $x = \frac{s}{(s-1)(s^{2}+4s+5)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring over the $5$ to the left and factor out $x$: $x(s^2+4s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-5$ Then combine terms on the right to get $x(s^2+4s)=\frac{s-5(s-1)}{s-1}$ Divide both sides by $s^2+4s$ and I come to $x=\frac{-4s+5}{(s-1)(s^2+4s)}$ which is different from what your book stated. In the event of doing PFD, you now have three denom's being $s$ , $s+4$ and $s-1$ with numerators $A,B,C$ This should be standard now. You may share with us your partial fractions. (Give it a try)