# Solving for $x$ in $x + \frac{s}{s^2+4} = \frac{2x}{s^2+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

How would I go about solving for $x$ in this equation?

$$x + \frac{s}{s^2+4} = \frac{2x}{s^2+4}$$

Comment: What did you try? Why not just subtract $x$ from each side?

Comment: I have tried substracting $x$ from both sides but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: After subtracting $x$, multiply the equation by $s^2+4$.

Comment: You have $x+A=Bx$ so $x=\frac{A}{B-1}$ when $B\neq 1$.

Comment: Can you please share the background :   Are your questions related? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695606/partial-fraction-decomposition-of-frac21s24-for-inverse-laplace-trans, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694451/solving-for-x-in-a-laplace-equation

Comment: And, note that $\frac{2}{s^2+4}$ is always smaller than $1$

Comment: I'm working with Laplace transformations and equations, but my questions are not related directly. It's mostly the algebra that I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x+\frac{s}{s^2+4}=\frac{2x}{s^2+4}\Longleftrightarrow x-\frac{2x}{s^2+4}=-\frac{s}{s^2+4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x\left[1-\frac{2}{s^2+4}\right]=-\frac{s}{s^2+4}\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{-\frac{s}{s^2+4}}{1-\frac{2}{s^2+4}}\Longleftrightarrow \color{red}{x=-\frac{s}{2+s^2}}$$

But notice then that: $s^2+2\ne0$ and $s^2+4\ne0$

Answer (score 3):

$$x+\frac{s}{s^2+4}=\frac{2x}{s^2+4}$$
$$\frac{s^2x+4x+s}{s^2+4}=\frac{2x}{s^2+4}$$
For real $s$, $s^2+4\ne0$. Hence,
$$s^2x+4x+s=2x$$
$$x(s^2+2)+s=0$$
$$x=-\frac{s}{s^2+2}$$